# "unable to create a null constant value of type 'anonymous type'" for nullable column in db

Tags: c#, json, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using EF and MVC to access data in a SQL database and am wishing the controllers to communicate using json (using REST from Android so not using the Views).

I found it necessary to change the controllers to project the data via anonymous objects to avoid a circular reference problem between the main and reference tables, however this has now lead to a new problem when trying to create the json for a collection of objects, when the underlying record(s) contains null in an optional foreign key field.

Table User has (for the sake of example) two foreign keys to code/description tables Language and Country, Language is mandatory and Country is optional.

I found I could successfully replace the Country element with null by testing for the null id., the json comes out fine...

```
{
"UserID": 3,
"UpdatedWhen": null,
"Country": null,
"Language": {
    "LanguageID": 1,
    "LocalName": "English"
    }
}
```

...but have now discovered that this doesn't work when I have multiple User objects to deal with.

```
    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        var users = from user in db.Users
                    select new
                    {   user.UserID,
                        < snip >
                        user.CreatedWhen,
                        user.UpdatedBy,
                        user.UpdatedWhen,
                        Country = (user.Country == null ? null : new { user.Country.CountryID, user.Country.LocalName }),
                        Language = new { user.Language.LanguageID, user.Language.LocalName } };

        return Json(users.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

From what I've read the problem is with my .ToList(), it doesn't like the null Country object, because if I deal with just a single user e.g.

```
    private object projectUser(User user)
    {
        return new
        {
            user.UserID,
            < snip >
            user.UpdatedWhen,
            Country = (user.Country == null ? null : new { user.Country.CountryID, user.Country.LocalName }),
            Language = new { user.Language.LanguageID, user.Language.LocalName } };
```

...it works just fine.

I've hunted about but simply cannot find a similar enough example of how to better do this, could anyone please suggest a way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you are not able to create a `null` constant value, in `linq to entity` queries, this is what this line `users.ToList()` tells you when you want to execute that....

and this method `private object projectUser(User user)` is worked, because the `user` have been already fetched in memory....

to solve your problem, you can fetch your data and then, select on your data in memory, like this:

```
var users = (from user in db.Users
             join country in db.Countries on user.CountryID equals country.ID into joinedList
             from country in joinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {user, country})
            .ToList()   // your data fetched to memory by this line
            .Select(u => new
            {
                 u.user.UserID,
                 u.user.CreatedWhen,
                 u.user.UpdatedBy,
                 u.user.UpdatedWhen,
                 Country = (u.country == null ? null : new { u.country.CountryID, u.country.LocalName }),
                 Language = new { u.user.Language.LanguageID, u.user.Language.LocalName } }
            })
            .ToList();
```

as alternative, you can set the properties of country `(anonymouse type)` to default values instead of `null`, like this:

```
var users = (from user in db.Users
             join country in db.Countries on user.CountryID equals country.ID into joinedList
             from country in joinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new {
                 user.UserID,
                 user.CreatedWhen,
                 user.UpdatedBy,
                 user.UpdatedWhen,
                 Language = new { user.Language.LanguageID, user.Language.LocalName },
                 Country = new { 
                     CountryID = country == null ? default(Guid) : country.CountryID,  // i assume type of CountryID is Guid
                     LocalName = country == null ? "" : country.LocalName 
                  }
              })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: An interesting approach, thanks for that.  It (first one) currently doesn't quite give the results I expected - all the countries are coming out null - but I can see where you're going with it.  I'll have a bit of a play and should be able to tweak it into working.  Thanks again.

Comment: is your data valid? with both of these query you get same result? if yes, i think something is worng in your data, or in join condition, needs to check this part of query `on user.CountryID equals country.ID`

Comment: Data is good, I'll get back to this part of the code later in the weekend, I'm just in the middle of getting the Android app talking to the Web Services, slightly complicated by the fact that Eclipse/Android is on Linux while the Web Services is running in a W7 VMware guest, slightly messy to debug.  back soon (ish)...

Comment: Couldn't seem to get this working, the linq simply wouldn't return what I wanted/expected no matter how I worked it, so I simply reworked the entire segment of my code so that it no longer required the two optional parts of the data.  Yes, I know it's a bit of a cop out but I needed to get past this and it was the quickest way and, as it happens, resulted in a slight simplification of my main code.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

break the queries and see whats the result in each step, to find out the problem is from your data or not :

```
var UsersQuery = (from user in db.Users
                  join country in db.Countries on user.CountryID equals country.ID into joinedList
                  from country in joinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  select new {user, country})
                  .ToList();   // your data fetched to memory by this line

var Users = UsersQuery.Select(u => new
        {
             u.user.UserID,
             u.user.CreatedWhen,
             u.user.UpdatedBy,
             u.user.UpdatedWhen,
             Country = (u.country == null ? null : new { u.country.CountryID, u.country.LocalName }),
             Language = new { u.user.Language.LanguageID, u.user.Language.LocalName } }
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: check to sure this part of query is ok, `user.CountryID equals country.ID`